# Change font color of alternate links for dynamic content in flask

Tags: css, flask, jinja2

I'm placing dynamic content on my screen using for loop and jinja templating in flask. I want to change the font color for alternate links placed. I have tried using `nth-child` as follows, but it doesn't seem to work.

### My Code

**Dynamic Content in Jinja Template**

```
        {% for item in data %}
        <div class="removeLink">
            <a id="link" href="{{item['link']}}">
                <div id="news">{{item['title']}}</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
```

**My CSS**

```
    #news{
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .removeLink a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .removeLink:last-child { 
        margin-bottom: 0px !important; 
    }       
    .removeLink:nth-child(2n) { 
        color: red !important; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue in my code so I'm answering my question. I edited my code as follows, with some javascript.

```
        <div id ="holder" class="removeLink">

            {% for item in data %}
            <a id="link" href="{{item['link']}}">
                <div id="news">{{item['title']}}</div>
            </a>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let elements = document.getElementById("holder").getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(let i=0; i<50; i++){
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            console.log(elements[i]);
            elements[i].style.color = "green";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#news` CSS selector has higher specificity for the link text than the `.removeLink:nth-child(2n)` selector.

Adjust the selector to create higher specificity. If you're interested, read more about
[css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The following should work:

```css
.removeLink:nth-child(2n) #news { 
    color: red !important; 
}
```